# log4net dynamic filename issue

Tags: logging, log4net

I'm using log4net and trying to get a filename format that looks like this:

```
AriaClient_2016_11_11_08_38_54-[7988].log
```

I have set up the configuration like this:

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
    <conversionPattern value="AriaClient_%date{yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss}-[%processid].log" />
  </file>
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <!--+InterProcessLock-->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date (#%property{pid}) [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

When generated, the filename comes out like this:

```
AriaClient_2016_11_11_08_38_54-[7988].2016-11-11.log
```

I don't understand where the second date is coming from before the .log extension. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score -1):

After 10 seconds to posted this post, I found that all I had to do was set `staticLogFileName` to true.